# What's UIGestureRecognizerState's changed and when should that be used?

Tags: ios9, uigesturerecognizer

What's UIGestureRecognizerState's changed and when should that be used?

```
public enum UIGestureRecognizerState : Int {
    case possible

    case began

    case changed // the recognizer has received touches recognized as a change to the gesture. the action method will be called at the next turn of the run loop

    case ended

    case cancelled

    case failed   
}
```